# Href doesn't appear in the browser whereas in the debugger it is present

Tags: php

I am working on an HTML problem. In the debugger there is a meaningful value for **href** attribute. But it will not appear in the browser.

```
            <div class="meta">
                Created By <a href="<?php get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?>
                </a>
                on <?php the_time('F j, Y g:i a'); ?>
            </div>
```

What am I missing here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You want `<?php echo ` or `<?=` not just `<?php`

Comment: `get_author_posts_url` _returns_ data, it does not directly create output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to print something with PHP, you need to use either `<?php echo/print ... ?>` or `<?= ... ?>`

```
<div class="meta">
  Created By <a href="<?= get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>"><?= the_author(); ?>
  </a>
  on <?= the_time('F j, Y g:i a'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. You should explain what you changed and why it solves the problem.

Comment: @Quentin give me some seconds :)

Comment: You should be voting to close as a simple typo, not answering.

Comment: @Nick there are plenty of answers of question like that. Why I should do that??

Comment: @Nick if you read my answer, you'll notice that it cannot be a simple typo.

Comment: "But, in the case your methods already do echo/print" — They don't.